# Read value from MySQL and compare which option is selected from drop-down list

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select, selected

```
<select name="title">

<selected value="<?php echo $title; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></selected>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs.</option>
<option value="Ms">Ms.</option>
<option value="Mr">Mr.</option>
<option value="Dr">Dr.</option>

</select>
```

I am trying to read a value from a column *Title* in a MySQL database, which is suppose to read the value, whether it be *Mr.*, *Ms.*, *Mrs.*, then compare it with the values in the drop-down list. It then lets the user select another title to then update the one stored in MySQL database.

I am creating a user profile. So when the user logs in and navigates to the view to edit a profile, he/she should be presented with a drop-down list containing the title he/she selected when registered. Then if he/she wants to they can change the title in the drop-down list and press the update button and it should now update to the new title in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `<select>` dropdown list in the following way,

```
<select name="title">
    <option value="Mrs"<?php if($title == "Mrs"){ echo " selected='selected'"; } ?>>Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Ms"<?php if($title == "Ms"){ echo " selected='selected'"; } ?>>Ms.</option>
    <option value="Mr"<?php if($title == "Mr"){ echo " selected='selected'"; } ?>>Mr.</option>
    <option value="Dr"<?php if($title == "Dr"){ echo " selected='selected'"; } ?>>Dr.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There is no *selected* HTML tag. Use the *selected* attribute of the [**option**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) tag:

> **selected**
>
> If present, this Boolean attribute indicates that the option is initially selected. If the <option> element is the descendant of a [<select>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element whose [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) attribute is not set, only one single <option> of this [<select>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element may have the selected attribute.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)</sup>

So consider this example from the [Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples) section of [the Mozilla Developer Network page for <select>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select):

```html
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
    <select name="select">
      <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
      <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
      <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
```

Your example code can be updated similarly:

```
<select name="title">
    <option value="Mrs" <?php if($title=="Mrs"){ echo "selected"; } ?>>Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Ms" <?php if($title=="Ms"){ echo "selected"; } ?>>Ms.</option>
    <option value="Mr" <?php if($title=="Mr"){ echo "selected"; } ?>>Mr.</option>
    <option value="Dr" <?php if($title =="Dr"){ echo "selected"; } ?>>Dr.</option>
</select>
```

A simpler way to do this would be to process the names first, using [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
<?php
$title = 'Dr';
$names = array('Mrs','Ms','Mr','Dr');
$options = array_reduce($names,function($carry,$name) use ($title) {
    return $carry .= '<option value="'.$name.'"'.($title == $name?' selected':'').'>'.$name.'.</option>';
});
?>
<select name="title">
    <?php echo $options;?>
</select>
```

See it in action in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/2uwbEzzzdzHSbb1w).

---

<sup>1</sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: Thanks for the help really appreciate it can you please upvote my question

Comment: The title for the upvote control is "_This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear_"... your question doesn't really show much research effort and could be more concise. You can read more about upvoting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).